# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'msmpi.lib' visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I am beginner in parallel programming using mpi for visual studio c++ 2010 , and i made steps in this tutorial for configuration :
http://supercomputingblog.com/mpi/getting-started-with-mpi-using-visual-studio-2008-express/
but when i try to build the project i have this error :

**LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'msmpi.lib'**

so any help ???

Comment: Ensure that you properly followed the instructions in Step 5

Answer (score 2):

I this this post can help you.
**add the msmpi to the linker**
http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=1938&sid=ffde2dad46d77320c7055ce0987b8a9d

Comment: The page doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

Solved ((fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'msmpi.lib'))
This Error is due to:

1.Erasure Some "Abaqus 6.14" File When we instal "Visual Studio 2010".

2.During installation "Visual Studio 2010" Prerequisite Windows software don't Work Corectly.

Solution:

1. Unistal All "Visual Studio 2010","Intel Parallel Studio XE 2013" and "Abaqus 6.14" file & Registry. (Use IObit Uninstaller)
2. Unistal All Prerequisite Windows software for "Visual Studio 2010" to be instal Again by "Visual Studio Ultimate 2010".
   (Prerequisite software = Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime, Microsoft Silverlight & All other Visual Studio 2010 Old file)
3. First Instal "Visual Studio Ultimate 2010" & "Intel Parallel Studio XE 2013" After Instal "Abaqus 6.14"
4. To verify in Command prompt type: abaqus verify -user_std
5. you get a PASS in the subroutine.
   ("Visual Studio 2015" With "Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016" work in "Abaqus 6.14" and get a PASS in the subroutine too)

Good luck

Arash Rahgozar, 
Graduat student in School of Civil Eng., College of Eng., University of Tehran